# How I can create DateTime with format "n Y" and control erroneus dates using DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

I need to create one date using only `month` and `year`.

I'm using this code:

```
$mData="1 2003";
$mDate=DateTime::createFromFormat("n Y", $mData);
var_dump($mDate);
```

Output in this case is fine:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2003-01-10 15:43:33.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Now I try with one month that not exists:

```
$mData="21 2003";
$mDate=\DateTime::createFromFormat("n Y", $mData);
var_dump($mDate);
```

Output is one date of september 2004!:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2004-09-10 15:45:26.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Why in this case `$mDate` is not `false` o any error occours?

It's not possible to create one valid `DateTime` object in this way controlling erroneus dates.

**In my scenario I can't to change the format `"n Y"` by another format,** then I need to achieve this controlling errors? It's possible?

Comment: What makes you think that the given date points to a month "that not exists"? It's a common practise to use such dates to avoid date calculations

Comment: @NicoHaase in In the [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) it says that `n` is one *Numeric representation of a month...* Why this method does this addition of values? Can you give me one link about that? I think thah when I use `createFromFormat()` it create one date based on the indicated format.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I try with one month that not exists 21

```
21 = 12 + 9 = 1y + 9m
```

Which is exactly what you are getting

```
string(26) "2004-09-10 15:45:26.000000"
```

Comment: But... what means `n Y` here: `createFromFormat("n Y", $mData);`? Is not `month Year`?

Comment: In the [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) it says that `n` is one *Numeric representation of a month...* Why this method does this addition of values?

Comment: Because it is more flexible. Negative values should also work

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, the behavior is the behavior, so you can check yourself:

```
$mData = "21 2003";

$a = explode(' ', $mData);

var_dump(
    checkdate($a[0], 1, $a[1])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the year from the DateTime Object is the same as the year of the input:

```
$mData = "13 2003";
$mDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat ("!n Y", $mData);


$error = ($mDate === false OR strpos($mData, $mDate->format('Y')) < 2) ;

var_dump($error);  //bool(true)
```

or you use date_get_last_errors(). This function provides a warning that you can evaluate.

```
$mData = "21 2003";
$mDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat ("!n Y", $mData);

var_dump(date_get_last_errors());
```

output:

```
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [7]=>
    string(27) "The parsed date was invalid"
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

**Note:**
The format "!n Y" results in a date with day 1 and time 00:00.

```
$mData = "5 2003";
$mDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat ("!n Y", $mData);

$error = ($mDate === false OR strpos($mData, $mDate->format('Y')) < 2) ;

var_dump($mDate,$error);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2003-05-01 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
bool(false)
```